# AppUpdateManager in Managed Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-update, android-enterprise

According to the documentation apps in managed devices

> are updated automatically when the following constraints are met:
>
> - The device is connected to a Wi-Fi network.
> - The device is charging.
> - The device is idle (i.e. not actively used).
> - The app to be updated is not running in the foreground.

Does these requirements override the AppUpdateManager if implemented in the app?
So the only way for the app itself to trigger an update (if these constraints are *not* met) is to set a service window?